# Laravel custom register table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, registration

I am trying to register an user using Laravel's native auth. Login works fine, but when I try to register a new user I get an error after submitting a form:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_db.user' doesn't exist
```

Of course, I made a table named `users` which I think has more sense and never had trouble up until now.

I am using `Entrust` for roles and permissions, so I had to change `auth.php` to:

```
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => User::class,
    ],
```

but even if I make this:

```
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => User::class,
        'table' => users
    ],
```

it submits a form on `user` table

Comment: Did you run the migrations? The `users` table is in the migrations provided by Laravel.

Comment: `users` and `password_reset` tables are already there in migration you have to run migrations

Comment: I told you I can log in...I couldn't log in if I hadn't ran the migrations first

Comment: @Norgul Can you check your `App\User` file? make sure that it has `protected $table = "users";`

Comment: it doesn't, but I tried with that also and it didn't work. Laravel automatically picks up plural table name of the model name, no?

Comment: according to the error, the query attempts inserting into `'my_db.user'` while your table is probably named **users** maybe in your model or config, you forgot writing the **s**

Comment: I know that...I am trying to find a point in registration where it says that `register` method is posting on `user` and not `users` so I can change it

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have properly created your model at `User.php` and correctly linked your `user` table.
For example `protected $table = 'user';`

Then make sure to change `validator` function in the `RegisterController.php`.

Note: I think you getting error while validating inputs, not submitting to database. Because it checks already registered users(uniqueness) on the database, before adding to it. So, carefully check your `email` validation.